# Lua alternative to optim()

Tags: r, optimization, programming-languages, lua

I'm currently looking for a lua alternative to the R programming languages; optim() function, if anyone knows how to deal with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://numlua.luaforge.net/ looks interesting but doesn't seem to have minimization. The most promising lead seems to be a [Lua wrapper for GSL](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/gsl-shell/), which has a variety of  [multidimensional minimization algorithms](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Multidimensional-Minimization.html) included.

[With derivatives](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Multimin-Algorithms-with-Derivatives.html)
 - BFGS (`method="BFGS"` in `optim`) and two conjugate gradient methods (Fletcher-Reeves and Polak-Ribiere) which are two of the three options available for `method="CG"` in `optim`.
 [Without derivatives](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Multimin-Algorithms-without-Derivatives.html)
 - the Nelder-Mead simplex (`method="Nelder-Mead"`, the default in `optim`).

More specifically, see [here](http://www.nongnu.org/gsl-shell/minim.html#minimizer-using-derivatives) for the Lua shell documentation covering minimization.

I agree with @Zack that you should try to use existing implementations if at all possible, and that you might need a little bit more background knowledge to know which algorithms will be useful for your particular problems ...

Comment: Then you're all set, provided that the wrapper I point to above works as advertised.

Answer (score 5):

R's implementation of `optim` isn't actually *written* in R.  If you type "optim" with no parentheses at the prompt, it'll dump out the definition of the function, and you can see that after some error checking and argument shuffling it invokes an `.Internal` routine (coded in C and/or Fortran) to do all the real work.

So your best bet is to find a C library for mathematical optimization -- sorry, I have no recommendations -- and wrap that into Lua.  I doubt anyone has written native-Lua code for this, and I would *not* recommend trying to code it yourself; doing mathematical optimization efficiently is still an active domain of basic research, and the best-so-far algorithms are decidedly nontrivial to implement.